# ReactJS file-loader not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I can't get the file loader module to work. When running this code I get this error:

*"You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."*

I've been googling a lot on this but can't find a solution. Any ideas?

**webpack.config.js:**

```html
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./client/index.html",
    filename: "index.html",
    inject: "body"
})

module.exports = {
    entry: "./client/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve("dist"),
        filename: "index_bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
            {
                test: /\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|svg)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        HtmlWebpackPluginConfig
    ]
}
```

**package.json:**

```html
{
  "name": "hello-world-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "webpack": "^2.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1"
  }
}
```

**App.jsx:**

```html
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <img src={require("./client/dog1.jpg")}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `.jsx` source file but you're telling Webpack to only use `babel-loader` for files ending in`.js`.  Fix the test in your Webpack config:

```
{ test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
```

Comment: PS: third hit on google for 'jsx webpack': https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html

Comment: I could swear I had support for both *.js and *.jsx before! Anyway, thank you very much for your help! :)